# ngrx: How to replace your complete state with an object?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to save and restore my app state from localStorage. Saving works nicely but being new to ngrx operators I'm not sure how to load it.

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    // Works but just realized that this should be an effect...
    this.store.select(state => state)
      .pipe(debounceTime(100))
      .subscribe(state => this.saveGameState(state));
  }

  hasData() {
    return localStorage.getItem('gameState') !== null;
  }

  async saveGameState(state: AppState) {
    localStorage.setItem('gameState', JSON.stringify(state));
  }

  loadData() {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameState'));
    // merge(this.store, of(data)); ?
    // this.store.dispatch(GameActions.restoreState(data)); // <- Something like this I suppose, but not sure where to dispatch it to
  }
}

...

// The state I want to replace (complex)
export interface AppState {
  resources: ResourceState;
  heroes: HeroState;
  reports: ReportState;
  game: GameState;
  missions: MissionState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  resources: resourceReducer,
  heroes: heroReducer,
  reports: reportReducer,
  game: gameReducer,
  missions: missionReducer,
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage ?

Comment: @maxime1992 That looks interesting. Thing is I'll hook it up to a DB later, making some sort of hybrid solution with localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Effects` for this purpose. You can make an initial `Effect` which runs once when the app is loaded. There you can `dispatch` your restore action.
Ex:

```js
 init$ = createEffect(() => defer(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameState'));
    this.store.dispatch(GameActions.restoreState(data));
 }), { dispatch: false });
```

Don't worry about `{dispatch: false}` because you don't return explicitly an action, you just dispatch a new action this is why `{ dispatch: false }`.
More about this package [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects).